# ffmpeg_kit_flutter :execute want get the success return code

Tags: flutter, video, ffmpeg, watermark

ffmpeg_kit_flutter getting return code 1 when while overlay the image over the video as watermark images

'-i assets/images/1.mp4 -i assets/images/poster_Watermark.png -filter_complex overlay=10:10 -codec:a copy $outPath' tried this command as FFmpegKit executation argument.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you solve it?

Comment: The logs show the problems. In my case, I solved it by solving the problems that the log showed.